# How to remove/uninstall tcltk-8.5.5-x11.dmg on mac

Tags: r

I installed tcltk-8.5.5-x11.dmg, as I need to run a R packages on Mac (OSX 10.9.5). However, I noticed that my R version already has a tcltk packages. So I want to remove/uninstall tcltk-8.5.5-x11.dmg. What should I do then? Your responses will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this on `superuser`. There you will get help better.

Comment: 8.5.5 is the version that R "expects". I don't see a problem. Furthermore, the .dmg file just has a package installer in it, so unless you have actually executed the package installer, you didn't actually do anything.